# Dropdown menu disappears when trying to hover on menu items

Tags: jquery

I've built a basic menu with one single dropdown. When I hover over the main menu item, the dropdown menu appears. When I try to select a menu item from the dropdown, it disappears. I've placed the dropdown outside of the `ul li` element because I need it to be full width and placing inside of the `li` wouldn't allow that.

HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <a href="">Logo</a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-9">
                         <ul>
                             <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                             <li class="dd-link"><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                         </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="dd-menu">
        <a href="">DD Menu 1</a>
        <a href="">DD Menu 2</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

 ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

 ul li ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dd-menu {
    position:absolute;
    top: 24px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    background-color: #def;
}
```

JS

```
 $('.dd-link').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('.dd-menu').stop(true, true).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('.dd-menu').stop(true, true).fadeOut(fadeSpeed);
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have you CSS as well?

Comment: The issue you is the mouse leaves .dd-menu when you hover over the links... you need to wrap them within the other.

Comment: So, you're saying I need to place `.dd-menu` inside the `li`?

Comment: Yep, I've posted an answer demonstrating a solution.

Comment: ANd there is really no need for JavaScript. Pure CSS can do it.

Comment: Alyus - epascarello's answer is great. You can just add `left: 0; right: 0;` to the `nav li > ul` styling to get full width submenus.

Comment: Even is the main menu and dropdown are within a grid?

Answer (score 2):

When you move you mouse from the `.dd-link` towards the newly shown `.dd-menu` you actually trigger the `mouseleave` event and hide them. If the menu is within the element class that triggers it to show (as below) then you are fine as you never leave the parent element.

**You can also do this with pure CSS, which is more advisable. There is a second demo below the jquery one demonstrating that.**

---

## Jquery Demo

```js
fadeSpeed = 300;
$('.dd-link').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('.dd-menu').stop(true, true).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('.dd-menu').stop(true, true).fadeOut(fadeSpeed);
  }
});
```

```css
.dd-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <ul>
  
  <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
    
    <li class="dd-link">
    
    <a href="">Link 2</a>
    
      <div class="dd-menu">
        <a href="">DD Menu 1</a>
        <a href="">DD Menu 2</a>
      </div>
    
    </li>
  
  </ul>


</header>
```

## CSS Demo

```css
.menu li{
  list-style-type: none;
}

.dd-menu {
  opacity: 0;
}

.dd-link:hover .dd-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .3s;
}
```

```html
<ul  class="menu">
      
      <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
        
        <li class="dd-link">
        
        <a href="">Link 2</a>
        
          <div class="dd-menu">
            <a href="">DD Menu 1</a><br>
            <a href="">DD Menu 2</a>
          </div>
        
        </li>
      
      </ul>
```

## Demo for your specific example

I've added a few classes and extra styling to create a typical nav menu with your structure. Hopefully it helps.

```js
fadeSpeed = 300;
$('.dd-link').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('.dd-menu').stop(true, true).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('.dd-menu').stop(true, true).fadeOut(fadeSpeed);
  }
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: black;
}

ul.navmenu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul.navmenu a {
  color: white;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.navmenu li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.dd-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 24px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: #def;
}

.dd-link:hover .dd-menu {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .3s;
}

ul.navmenu .dd-menu a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>

  <div class="navbar">

    <ul class="navmenu">
      <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
      <li class="dd-link"><a href="">Link 2
        </a>
        <div class="dd-menu">
          <a href="">DD Menu 1</a>
          <a href="">DD Menu 2</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: I've applied your suggestion to place the dropdown menu inside of the `li`, however, the dropdown menu does not span the full width of the page which is why I think I placed the dropdown outside of the `ul` element.

Comment: Updated to include an example for your situation, but you should check out epascerello's answer

Comment: Thank you for the example, however, I've also made a mistake within my initial code. I've updated my code.

Answer (score 1):

It hides because the mouse moves outside the li. So to make your code work, the code would need to be in the li or you have to add complicated logic to see if the element that you focused is the sub menu.

Easiest thing is simple CSS can make menus appear on hover, no need for JavaScript. Place the sub nav inside the li and apply hover to your li.

```css
nav ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

nav li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 0;
}

nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav li > ul {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #CCC;
  max-height: 0;
  opacity:0;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-out, opacity 0.25s ease-out;
  overflow: hidden;
}


nav li:hover > ul,
nav li:focus-within ul {
  max-height: 500px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: max-height 0.75s ease-out, opacity 0.75s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Text 1</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Text 1 - 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text 1 - 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text 1 - 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Text 2</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Text 2 - 1 with longer text than whatever</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text 2 - 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text 2 - 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Text 2 - 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example, however, my previous code was missing a few elements. The dropdown is placed within a grid and also needs to be full width when visible. One of the reasons I placed the dropdown on the outside of the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the same events to `.dd-menu` and don't set `jumpToEnd` in the `.stop()` methods to true:

```
$('.dd-link, .dd-menu').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('.dd-menu').stop(true).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('.dd-menu').stop(true).fadeOut(fadeSpeed);
  }
});
```

---

Demo

```js
var fadeSpeed = 300;

$('.dd-link, .dd-menu').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $('.dd-menu').stop(true).fadeIn(fadeSpeed);
  },
  mouseleave: function() {
    $('.dd-menu').stop(true).fadeOut(fadeSpeed);
  }
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
ul li ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dd-menu {
  position:absolute;
  top: 24px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: #def;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
        <a href="">Logo</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-9">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
          <li class="dd-link"><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dd-menu">
    <a href="">DD Menu 1</a>
    <a href="">DD Menu 2</a>
  </div>
</header>
```